# avoiding zero float division in loops - python

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, divide-by-zero

sorry i am a bit of a newbie with programming but I am getting a float division error in a simple loop which I am not sure how to rectify.

Here is a code in python 2.7

```
import random

N = 100
A = []
p = 0
q = 0

k = 1
while k<=N:
    x = random.random()
    if x<= 0.5:
        p+= 1
    else:
        q+=1
    y = p/q
    A.append(y)
    k+=1
```

Running this code gives a zero division error. which I am not able to rectify. Can anyone tell me how to rectify this?

Comment: You set 'q' to zero and after first random less or equal 0.5 you have division by zero - simple.

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help, what i figured out is that replacing y = p/q with y = p/(q+0.000001) solves the issue. Although it feels a bit like cheating, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting zero division error because of this code

```
if x <= 0.5:
    p+=1
else:
    q+=1
y= p/q
```

You have initialised q = 0 thus when while loop is run first time and if x <= 0.5 then p will be incremented but q will be equal to zero and in next step you are dividing p by q(which is zero). You need to put a check condition before performing division so that denominator is not zero. You can rectify it in following manner.

```
if x <= 0.5:
    p+=1
else:
    q+=1
if (q == 0):
    print "Denominator is zero"
else:
    y= p/q
```

This is just one solution since I don't know what you are trying to do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.nextafter(q, 1).
This gives you the next floating-point value after q towards 1, which is very small number.